# How can a view be notified that it's no longer visible

Tags: android

I have a view that may be still animating when the user navigates away from the activity. Is there some sort of equivalent to **onPause()** or **onStop()** to notify the view that its services are no longer required?

Comment: [`onDetachedFromWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow%28%29) would probably be the right place to put that logic.

Comment: If the view is part of an Activity, you may also want to take a look on [onWindowFocusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)

Comment: @MH, I wound up using your solution; feel free to make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: Sweet. Glad to hear that worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

[`onDetachedFromWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow%28%29) would probably be the right place to put that logic.